# Should I use a GoPro as a small camera for taking pictures in and outside?

Tags: compact-cameras, gopro

I just want to buy a small camera for taking some indoor and outdoor pictures.

Comment: Are you asking whether the GoPro will serve as a general-purpose camera in addition to its main purpose?

Comment: A few things, you need to specify exactly which GoPro as the new models vary considerably from the old especially in low light. Further, the above question I linked to seems to already answer the general question, if you do have a different question here, then please point that out and precisely what different question you have.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate... too much time has passed, and those answers on the other thread are pretty much wrong for today's GoPro cameras. Those answers don't even address current models you can actually buy today. So what do we do if we want to answer this with a more correct answer from this year?

Comment: I was thinking in Silver edition. The main propose is to have just one good photo & movie camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GoPro is a tiny ruggedized video camera, designed mainly for helmet camera style mounting. It shoots stills, but this feature is only really designed as a last resort if you can only take one camera with you. The GoPro has no screen or viewfinder so you have no idea what you're going to get in the frame when composing your shots.

Unless you also need to shoot video, you'd get much better results from a small digital stills camera. For a list of recent ultra-compact cameras and their features see here:

http://www.dpreview.com/products/search/cameras#criterias=SpecsCoreParams&includeDiscontinued=No&sort=newestFirst&view=list&page=1&paramSpecsCoreParamsBodyType=UltraCompact

Answer (score 1):

A GoPro is good at what it does in a dedicated range of applications.
It is hard to use as a general purpose camera and/or will cost much more to configure it to do so.

If you need need ruggedness, waterproofness and smallish size and weight then its value for money is reasonable.

If you don't need the first two then you can get far more for your money or pay far less for what you get by buying something else.